# insert order number into wp ecommerce order confirmation email

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

A client site has been barred from using Paypal, so their WP-e-Commerce catalog/cart now has to use manual EFT bank payments to accept money from customers.  A customer receives this banking information in their order confirmation email.

When a customer makes an EFT payment through their bank website, they have the opportunity to insert a reference to accompany the payment.  This is a string of text.

We'd like to send the order number in the order confirmation email, so the customer can use the order number as the EFT reference, so the client site can match EFT payments and orders.

**How do we insert the order number into the order confirmation email?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wp-e-commerce admin, Settings -> Store -> Admin, you can customise the Customer Purchase Receipt (confirmation email) template to add this, e.g.

`Please quote %purchase_id% as reference when paying by EFT.`

There are a couple of hooks in wp-e-commerce that let you insert other data into the confirmation emails:

- wpsc_transaction_result_cart_item -- this is called for each item in the cart array
- wpsc_transaction_result_message -- this is called to filter the text of the email
- wpsc_transaction_result_message_html -- this is called to filter the on-page confirmation

You can get more information about the whole deal on a [blog post I wrote a while ago](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/extend-notification-emails-in-wp-e-commerce/#comment-1833) (NB: pre-3.8.9 which changed things slightly!)